# drop down choice column in new and edit forms require two click in ie

Tags: dropdown

For a SharePoint 2007 site using internet Explorer (version 8 on a Windows XP system), drop-down choice columns require first clicking on a selection and then either clicking outside the drop down or pressing Enter to make a selection.

Using Firefox, all that is required is to click on a drop-down item to select it. This is the behavior I'd like to replicate for those using IE.

I believe this has something to do with IE having problems with onfocus?

Is there any way to correct this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE renders drop dows with less than 20 items differently than with more than 20.  If the number is less that 20, it behaves exactly like Firefox.  If it's more than 20, it renders differently whereas Firefox functions in the same way.  Based on what you're saying, I'm assuming your drop down list has more than 20 items.

There is a [SPServices operation](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPComplexToSimpleDropdown) that will convert these complex drop downs into the normal dropdowns like Firefox if you can use jQuery on your form.

Marc also explains it nicely on his [blog](http://sympmarc.com/2010/05/19/two-types-of-sharepoint-forms-dropdowns/).